# Value inside dropdown doesn't seem to change with onChange handler - MUI Select using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to update dropdown values using MUI's `Select` component but I can't get to update using `onChange` handler, the `value` remains same always even though I select a new item in the dropdown.

I created a working example using [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-in-table-dfdvq?file=/demo.js). Could anyone please help?

Excerpt from my code

```
export default function Cars() {
  const rows = [
    {
      make: "BMW",
      model: "X3",
      type: "Suv"
    },
    {
      make: "VW",
      model: "Jetta",
      type: "Sedan"
    }
  ];

  const handleChange = (e, row, index) => {
    console.log("dropdown value -> ", e.target.value);
    console.log("row -> ", row);
    row.type = e.target.value;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Make</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Model</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Type</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map((row, index) => (
              <TableRow key={row.make}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.make}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.model}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  <FormControl>
                    <InputLabel>Type</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                      value={row.type}
                      label="Type"
                      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, row, index)}
                    >
                      <MenuItem value="Sedan">Sedan</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem value="Suv">Suv</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                  </FormControl>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to keep the current state of your `rows` data and update the array in your `handleChange` function like this:

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([
    {
      make: "BMW",
      model: "X3",
      type: "Suv"
    },
    {
      make: "VW",
      model: "Jetta",
      type: "Sedan"
    }
]);

const handleChange = (e, row, index) => {
    console.log("dropdown value -> ", e.target.value);
    console.log("row -> ", row);
    const copyRows = [...rows];
    copyRows[index].type = e.target.value;
    setRows(copyRows);
};
```

You can take a look at [this forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-in-table-forked-9o4rz) for a live working example.